# Tableview with section per contact's first letter

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm doing a Array and I'm trying to put it into an index list and alphabetical order but I'm getting error.

Here's my twoDimensionalArray

```
 var contacts = [
     ExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, names: ["Hong Kong", "Bangkok, Thailand", "London, UK", "Singapore", "Bali, Indonesia"].map{ Contact(name: $0, hasFavorited: false) }),
       ]
```

Here's the error. Please help can't figure out how to fix it

```
      func createContactDict() {
                for contact in contacts {
                    // Get the first letter of the contact name and build the dictionary
                    let firstLetterIndex = contacts.index(contacts.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
                    let contactKey = String(contacts[..<firstLetterIndex]) 

                    if var contactValues = contactsDict[contactKey] {
                        contactValues.append(contacts)
                        contactsDict[contactKey] = contactValues
                    } else {
                        contactsDict[contactKey] = [contact]
                    }
                }
```

Here's some code related to UITableViewDataSource

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let contactKey = contactSectionTitles[section]
        guard let contactValues = contactsDict[contactKey] else { return 0 }

        return contactValues.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
        cell.link = self
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.section].names[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = contact.name

        cell.accessoryView?.tintColor = contact.hasFavorited ? UIColor.red : .lightGray

        if showIndexPaths {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.name)   Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)"
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Then do `let tempPartialContact = contacts[..<firstLetterIndex]`, check what's its type, then `let contactKey = String(tempPartialContact)`, and check if there is a specific init for it. You might need to tell the compiler what's `tempPartialContact` type.

Comment: now I'm getting error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an argument of type 'ArraySlice<ExpandableNames>' " please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you can do it in two lines:

```
func createContactDict() {
    let contactNames = Array(contacts.map { $0.names }.joined())
    contactsDict = Dictionary(grouping: contactNames, by: { String($0.name.prefix(1)) })
}
```

First line converts `[ExpandableNames]` to `[Contact]`

Second line creates dictionary, where keys are described as first letter of name `String($0.name.prefix(1))`.

---

Reffering to you problem with UITableViewDatasource, I guess, that you need to go to method `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt:)` and change this line:

`let contact = contacts[indexPath.section].names[indexPath.row]`

into:

```
let contactKey = contactSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
let contact = contactsDict[contactKey][indexPath.row]
```

Comment: the errors went away but nothing showed up on the table

Comment: You didn't mention about table before - without more context it's hard to answer

Comment: yeah sorry about that its in a uitableview

Comment: Ok, so now you have problem with implementation of your `UITableViewDatasource`, which looks like another problem, not related with this question - this question is about mapping your `[ExpandableNames]` to dictionary.

Comment: Edit your question and add there some code related to `UITableViewDatasource`, I will try to help you.

Comment: ok done sorry it took a while, couldn't add a lot on the title cause it has limited characters

Comment: I also buttons in the accessory view just to let you know, but there not showing up as well.